# MySQL query runs 5x slower on staging server than local dev maching

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

I've got a query that is running 5x slower on my staging server as opposed to my local dev machine.

Stackoverflow doesn't want to play nicely with the formatting; the query, describes, and explains are located [here](https://gist.github.com/4270389)

Looking at the `describe` statements, I can't see any difference between the local and remote schemas.

The record counts for the 2 machines are in the same order of magnitude (500k vs 600k)

**Edit In Response to Comments**

It was my highly unscientific approach of throwing the queries into MySQL Workbench and looking at the query time.  The local query time was on the order of 1.3 seconds and the remote query time was on the order of 5.2 seconds (so its 4x as slow).  I'm sure there's a better way to test this query time.

The machines are different.  My dev machine is a Mac Book Pro with 8 gigs of RAM.  The staging server is a linode VPS with 512 megabytes of RAM.  There shouldn't be much load on the staging server (I'm the only one that uses it).  I've noticed most queries run in approximately the same time frame on the local machine and staging server, so I was confused as to why this one had such a drastically different time frame.

**RAM Issue**

Since a temporary table isn't being used (no mention in the `EXPLAINS`), is the amount of RAM still an issue?

**Output from `free`**

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:        508576     453880      54696          0       4428     254200
-/+ buffers/cache:     195252     313324
Swap:       262140      19500     242640
```

**Profiling Added to Gist**

It looks like the remote is taking 2.5 seconds 'sending data' whereas the local is only taking 0.5 seconds. Is this an I/O issue? (Complete profiling info in gist)

Comment: Well, are the two machines of similar specs?

Comment: How do you know it's *running* 5x more slowly?

Comment: Also, is there anything else running against your staging server?

Comment: Updated the question to hopefully answer the questions posed

Comment: Have you run the query multiple times?  You can never base timings on initial runs, because caches are filled which are used for subsequent processing.

Comment: Amount of RAM available to MySQL does matter. So does disk IO speed.

Comment: The queries have been run multiple times.  I found this slow query by looking through my logs for the last few days of activity and noticed this perpetually slow query.  Then today I ran it locally to see if I could optimize it

Comment: @SalmanA - Can it matter to the affect of 4x the speed?

Comment: @Tyler: yes, it can. Your dev machine has 16x times the amount of RAM that the other machine has.

Comment: Less memory will cause MySQL to use disk for temporary calculations; and disk IO is much slower than memory. However, I do not see a "Using temporary" in your explains so it may not be a too-little-memory issue.

Comment: @SalmanA - That's what I was thinking.  But I could be drastically wrong

Comment: @TylerDeWitt x4 is quite few if the machine is actually swapping, you'd be lucky in that case ;)

Comment: Can you include the profile breakdowns in your question, please?

Comment: @Dancrumb - I couldn't get the formatting to carry over on SO, so I put the profiling info in the gist.  Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your staging server has one sixteenth of the RAM that you Mac Book Pro has.

Without knowing how much RAM is available to your two instances of MySQL, it's hard to be definitive, but that's the first place I'd look.

Also, if you run these queries from the MySQL command line, locally, how do the times compare?
It could be that the increase in time is in network transfer and not query processing.

Actually... network transfer time is the first place I'd look... then MySQL memory usage.

### EDIT following question updates

The 'sending data' phase is the phase where the server is sending data to the client [ref](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/general-thread-states.html). I don't know exactly how large your dataset is, but 2.5s seems pretty high for what's probably 50kB of data or so.
Having looked at the profiling data, nearly all the time is spent sending data, so I'd strongly suspect the network here.

### EDIT 2

Some research lead me to [this page](http://petewarden.typepad.com/searchbrowser/2008/10/how-to-profile-mysql.html) which indicates that the 'Sending data' is misleading and that this is *actually* the time spend executing your query.

Thus, I really think you need to be looking at CPU and memory usage on your server since it's specced at a level so much lower than your MacBook.

Comment: How can I check the network transfer time vs query time? Is that taken care of by just ssh'ing into the machine and running these commands from the command line?

Comment: @TylerDeWitt Yes. And I strongly agree on the memory point. What does ``free`` tell you about swap usage?

Comment: @Tyler: try using profiling commends, e.g. `SET profiling = 1; SELECT <your time cinsuming query>; SET profiling = 0; SHOW PROFILE;`. It provides a breakup of time MySQL spends on various operations. Compare local vs remote.

Comment: @TylerDeWitt yes: SSH into the machine and use the cli client. After the query, it will report the execution time.
Alternatively, use the profiling commmands that Salman A suggests

Comment: Yes, profile them. The EXPLAIN plans look identical so the network time maybe the issue.

Comment: Updated the gist with profiling information.  There was a big difference in `sending data`

Comment: @Dancrumb - What still seems pretty high? And agreed, since the only thing being returned is an integer (`select COUNT...`), there shouldn't be much information to transmit to the client.  Since I ssh'ed into the machine and ran those commands in the cli, does that `send data` include the time to send the info to my terminal or is it just executed locally?  We have really bad internet at work, so if there is a network issue, it likely is on our side

Comment: No... the time reported by the cli, if run on your server, will not include the time spent printing to the terminal... the cli is the 'client' in this instance, so the 'sending data' time should be pretty low.

Comment: Since the profiling information came from the cli of the server with mysql running on it, do you have any idea on how the `sending data` time could be so high? There shouldn't be any network interference, since they are running on the same machine? Or does the VPS play a part in this?

Comment: I thought you were running with MySQL Workbench. Is this *not* the case?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I ssh'd into the remote server and ran all these commands from the cli there.  The profiling information is taken from the cli running on the remote machine.

Comment: @Dancrumb - any idea what might be causing the long `sending time` if the commands are being run in the cli?